# Calculate centroids from a Kernel Density

Tags: r, r-sp, kernel-density, centroid, adehabitathr

I have two R-related questions:

1. I'm trying to calculate centroids from a kernelUD. I was able to calculated the KernelUD, and I end up with a S4 object of class estUD. However, I cannot find a way to calculate a centroid from this probabiltiy distribution. I'm aware of the use of MCP for centroids, but I was wondering if it was possible calculate them from the KD estimation.
2. Once I have centroids, how do I compare the distance between them?

This is the paper from where I got the code:
https://rs.figshare.com/articles/R_code_-_home_ranges_and_NBDA_from_Multi-network-based_diffusion_analysis_reveals_vertical_cultural_transmission_of_sponge_tool_use_within_dolphin_matrilines/8867933

This is an example of the dataset I'm working with:

```
  project      Date alliance letterCode longitude  latitude Year
1       1 19-giu-17        5        GRI  114.6551 -25.30376 2017
2       1 19-giu-17        5        GRI  114.6494 -25.41278 2017
3       1 19-giu-17        5        KRI  114.6066 -25.96792 2017
4       1 19-giu-17        5        VEE  114.6551 -25.11376 2017
5       1 19-giu-17        5        VEE  114.6494 -25.31278 2017
6       1 02-lug-17        5        AJA  114.6152 -25.74132 2017
```

Comment: You have to provide code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.